# Permission popup appear multiple time

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, permissions

I have a project in swift 2.When I launch the app first time there are three different type of permissions popup (Push notification, Location, Photo) that appear on the splash screen.I have add the Permission for location and photos in info.plist

The problem is when the app lunched the one(location) popup appear and disappear without any click then other(photos) popup appear and disappear after few seconds without any click.After few seconds the popup appear one by one and now the popup are display on the screen until I click any one option.

I want to display the permission popup only once when user tap on the button.I have searched about it but all the solutions that I found are in latest version of swift. Any suggestion regarding this is appreciated.

```
import CoreLocation

private var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
private var locationHandler: ((location: CLLocation?,error: NSError?) -> Void)?

locationManager = CLLocationManager()
locationManager.delegate = self
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()



 func requestCurrentLocation(completionHandler:((location: CLLocation?,error: NSError?)->Void)!) {
    locationHandler = completionHandler
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        locationManager.requestLocation()
    } else {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

  func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let locationHandler = locationHandler, let location = locations.first {
        locationHandler(location: location, error: nil)
        self.locationHandler = nil
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
}



func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    if let locationHandler = locationHandler {
        locationHandler(location: nil, error: error)
        self.locationHandler = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that without writing the code the permission dialog comes. Just adding permission in plist won't show the dialog

Comment: @InderKumarRathore, Please check. i have added the code for location.

Comment: Where do you request location permission?

Comment: I have a NSObject type class.All the above code is written in that class. I have added the  request location in the init method of the class

Answer (score 0):

The key is CLLocationManager always alive

```
import CoreLocation

class LocationManager: NSObject {

    static let shared = LocationManager()

    private lazy var locationManager: CLLocationManager = {

        let manager = CLLocationManager()
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.delegate = self
        return manager
    }()

    private override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    func askForPermission() {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

    func requestLocation() {
        locationManager.requestLocation()
    }
}


extension LocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        // do something
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        // do something
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        // do something
    }
}
```